# How can I set an api token in php?

Tags: php, database, api, bubble.io

I am currently working on my website, so at the moment I have a website which I made with Bubble.io (no-code), and what I want to do is develop a CRM website with php , what I want to do is connect my database from my Bubble.io website to be able to use the data on my CRM website, Bubble.io can give me the data in JSON format which is good, but not secure , to secure the data I can generate a token api, so my question is: how can I give the token api to php so that I can retrieve the data.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? Also _give the token api_ what do you mean by 'give'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API endpoint should have a parameter that allows you to pass the token.

Example

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://developers.google.com&key=yourAPIKey
```

Is there documentation available with the API that you are using?

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually I solved the problem by adding "?api_token=my_token" to my api link and this works fine.